# What's the cheapest way to get the value of the two leftmost bits of a number?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I want to return 0,1,2 or 3 based on wether the 2 leftmost bits are 00 01 10 or 11.

When I wanted the two rightmost bits I just used `%4`. 
I see that I can right-shift my int by the right position (ex 30 if it is 32 bits) and then use %4, but that's 2 operations. Is there a "one opcode" way ?

Comment: Who said `%4` is always one opcode?

Comment: @NeilButterworth. But shifted over.

Comment: @OP, are you doing this just once or in a loop?

Comment: You didn't mention whether the number is signed or not. If it is unsigned, then the right shift is sufficient and the masking is redundant.

Comment: The compiler is probably smart to optimize your `%4` into  a mask anyway, but if it isn’t, division and modulo are much, *much* slower than masking or other bit manipulation.

Comment: On unsigned you need mask only if you get not leftmost bits (to get rid of bits that on the left) so for leftmost shift is sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

If you're working with a 32-bit integer, a right-shift by 30 is sufficient.

```
uint32_t get_value(uint32_t val) {
    return val >> 30;
}
```

If you're working with a 64-bit integer, you'll need to change the value you shift by:

```
uint64_t get_value(uint64_t val) {
    return val >> 62;
}
```

Comment: I'd emphasize that **unsigned** integer is required for this to work properly

Comment: If it's not unsigned, you need the mask because the worst that can happen is the higher bits will be filled. It will still work correctly.

Comment: Also, the input and output types make it very clear that the numbers as unsigned.

Comment: Mask is not necessary if you are shifting by 62 in the second case either.

Comment: I've fixed it. For some reason I thought that, when using a 64-bit number, you'd want the 31st and 32nd bits....

Comment: @MadPhysicist If it’s not unsigned, the result is implementation-defined; it’s only *probably* twos-complement arithmetic shift. For any sort of shifting operation, or any other bitwise operation for that matter, you probably want to cast to unsigned first.

Comment: In fact, I want to do the same thing afterwards for the newt two bits, and so on. (so it would be a {val <<2 k; return (val >> 30)  where k ranges from 0 to 15). Is there a single step operation like your solution for the first 2 bits ?

Comment: @DanielH. There are very few non-twos complement architectures out there at the moment. I looked that up at one point, and it is **extremely** unlikely that OP is on one of them. But yes, casting to unsigned first is a good idea.

Comment: @AaaBbb. No, there is not unfortunately. You can mask then shift if that makes you any happier, but to do that in a generic way, you would have to shift the mask too, so it's really not worth it.

Comment: @AaaBbb You should edit your question with the whole problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @MadPhysicist True, but I would be much less surprised if there were compilers which didn’t define it to be arithmetic right-shift for some reason.

Comment: if the instruction set does not have a single instruction to implement this (assumed unsigned 32 bit) then it may still be multiple operations.

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't hurt to go for a generic solution:

```
template <typename UnsignedInteger>
inline UnsignedInteger 
    top_two_bits(UnsignedInteger value)
{
    return value >> ((sizeof(UnsignedInteger) << 3) - 2);
}
```

Just makes things easier should you decide to use a different unsigned-integer type further down the line. In any case, the compiler should be able to inline the entire expression in such a way that it's just as efficient as a macro or whatnot.

***EDIT***

Also, (and this may well be overkill, but just to round out the example) you can use simple template meta-programming techniques to create something that works seamlessly with any type of integer, without compromising efficiency:

```
template <typename SignedInteger, bool IsSignedInteger>
struct duduce_sign_dispatch_
{
    static inline SignedInteger
        top_two_bits(SignedInteger value)
    {
        return (value >> ((sizeof(SignedInteger) << 3) - 2)) & SignedInteger(3);
    }
};

template <typename UnsignedInteger>
struct duduce_sign_dispatch_<UnsignedInteger, false>
{
    static inline UnsignedInteger
        top_two_bits(UnsignedInteger value)
    {
        return value >> ((sizeof(UnsignedInteger) << 3) - 2);
    }        
};

template <typename Integer>
inline Integer 
    top_two_bits(Integer value)
{
    return duduce_sign_dispatch_<Integer, (~Integer() < 0)>::top_two_bits(value);
}
```